How to clone or monkey patch a React Component so one method changes
Let's say we have
class OriginalComponent extends Component {
  // various code..
  someFunction = () => {
    // does stuff
  }
}

I want to get the functionality of OriginalComponent but with the change that someFunction is replaced with different functionality.
I can think of two possible ways to do this:

Define NewComponent through inheritance:

class NewComponent extends OriginalComponent {
  // various code..
  someFunction = () => {
    // does new stuff
  }
}


Directly change the prototype on OriginalComponent:

OriginalComponent.prototype.methodName = function() 
{ 
  // does new stuff
}

Do both of these methods work?  Do they differ?  What is recommended here.
I am using a third party library that allows me to pass in overrides for particular React components in the config, for context.
